# Does Windows 7 supports Google Email Uploader?

Tags: windows-7

Is `google email uploader` available in `windows 7`...... I am using `Outlook 2007` as my desktop email program.... I thought of uploading all my mails to a new gmail account which i created..

But from System requirements of [google email uploader](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/email_uploader.html)

- Windows XP and Vista
- Outlook 2003 and greater for Outlook
  support.
- A Google Apps account
- Microsoft .NET 2.0.

If you do not have 2.0, the program will install it for you.

Is it available for windows 7....

Comment: Just try and you will know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it fully supports Windows 7.

Comment: @Wil I dont have windows 7 one of my client has... I showed this page to him.. He started with google email uploader..

Comment: @pandiya Generally, if it's supported in XP and/or Vista, it'll work just fine in Windows 7. Microsoft spends a great deal of time ensuring that new OS systems are backwards-compatible.